# Alternative way of passing system/environment variable to service (glassfish)

Tags: centos, web-applications, glassfish

I have a glassfish application server that is running under the glassfish user on CentOS 7.2. I have an application that has a deployed application that is needing a custom environment variable (e.g. `export App_Home=/opt/App`).

The application is reading the environment variables in Java with within glassfish with `System.getenv("App_Home")`.

I was able to get this to work by editing the service.

```
vi /etc/systemd/system/glassfish.service
```

Adding `EnvironmentFile=/opt/MyApp/MyEnvironmentFile`
and then in `/opt/MyApp/MyEnvironmentFile` added
`App_Home=/opt/MyApp`

1. Is there a way of setting this environment variable with glassfish itself?
2. Or is there a better way of setting the system property variables instead of editing service files?

I also tried adding exports into the glassfish .bashrc (which is what shell the service seems to be running under) but that didn't seem to get passed down to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently there is an asenv.conf file in the glassfish directory. You could edit that (environment file).

bashrc files are used for login shells and as you have already seen for yourself, not useful for services.

Comment: I thought that was a solution as well too but that doesn't work either. I tried to add my `App_Home...` but when I printed out the System.getenv() from within the application it wasn't listed.

Comment: then you could modify the startserv script and add your variable there (it's a shell script, so something like export MY_AWESOME_VAR="my_awesome_value" should be enought (I just tested it and i can see the variable in /prod/pid#/environ , so I know it works)

Comment: In my glassfish.service file the ExecStart= is pointing to a jar file and start-domain which starts the glassfish service. I take it yours is pointing to just a script and not a jar file?

Comment: no, startserv is in the glassfish5/glassfish/bin/ directory of the unpacked latest-web.zip I downloaded from https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download

Comment: My glassfish.service file has the following line and is what starts the service. `ExecStart = /usr/bin/java -jar /home/glassfish/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar start-domain` I don't think the file in the startserv script is ever called which results in it never having that export ran.

Comment: you could modify your systemd file, I guess. Then it would just point to the startserv script. But do what suits you, I have already given you an alternative way of passing a variable which was what you were asking for.

Comment: I appreciate it. It does give me another option and that is what I ended up doing to try and keep the service clean. I honestly think the more interesting thing you showed was the `/proc/pid#/environ` information. Wasn't aware of that and can see that coming in handy in the future. Appreciate it. I accepted your answer.

Comment: great to know it was helpful.